# Is Form Feed character (FF) valid in MISRA C2 standard

Tags: c, misra

Opening some legacy code in Notepad++ and notice a few occurrences of **FF** character below function comment headers.  They are ASCII code 12 which is the Form Feed character.  Are FF characters valid in MISRA C2 standard please?  Apologies I don't have access to PC-Lint/QAC checker.

Comment: A form-feed is explicitly allowed as separating white space in the C89/99/11 standard. (Section 6.4.3, "Preprocessing tokens can be separated by white space; this consists of comments (described later), or white-space characters (space, horizontal tab, new-line, vertical tab, and form-feed), or both." (You can ignore the "preprocessing token" part here.) I'm not familiar with MISRA, though I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't talk about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be talking about a commercial product, whose announcements give no useful information, e.g., this [press release](http://www.programmingresearch.com/press-releases/2013/prqa-announces-support-for-misra-c2012/).

Form feed is stated explicitly to be part of the character set in **ISO/IEC 9899:199 (E)** *5.2.1 Character sets*.  If the tool advised you not to use a documented, standard feature, that would be a defect in the tool itself.  A comparable issue would be whether to allow tab characters in leading whitespace on a line.

Given that context, the use of form feed characters is a *stylistic* issue unrelated to static analysis, and I would not expect the two to be confused in a commercial product.

Answer (score 1):

MISRA-C:2004 3.2 merely states that the character set and the corresponding encoding should be documented (for example by a reference to the relevant ISO standard). You are only allowed to use *character constants and string literals* that exist in that standard.

But there is no such requirement on source code comments.